# Python web server lxml.etree symbol error causing import error

Tags: python, webserver, lxml, elementtree

I have some code in a module called `XMLModel.py` that parses an XML object with `lxml.etree`. When I try importing `lxml.etree` generically in an IPython or regular Python shell, it works fine. Command line versions of my code all work fine.

But when I try to have Apache execute the code as part of a web page, I get a bizarre import error:

```
File "/var/www/html/../ws/python-util/src/util/XMLModel.py", line 4, in <module>
    import lxml.etree
ImportError: /opt/epd/7.3-2/lib/libxslt.so.1: undefined symbol: xmlXPathCompiledEvalToBoolean
```

I've searched for this "undefined symbol" problem but cannot make any sense about it. It might have something to do with building a static instead of dynamic version of `lxml` but I cannot find anything that spells it out clearly.

Has anyone else had this kind of problem specifically within a browser setting? What could make the import suddenly fail when the code is used that way?

My operating system is Red Hat 4.1.2-48. The directory /opt/epd is just where I store the Enthought Python distribution and then also place related modules, .so stuff, etc. It's all very standard.

Comment: What OS? What is in /opt/epd?

Comment: I updated the question with this info.

Comment: Are you sure Apache is using the same python binary you're using from the command line?

Comment: Yes, I can confirm that by investigating the Python versions and also getting it to print out an Exception when rendering the web page, and listing various system path attributes, etc.

Comment: Both are using Python 2.7.3. And I also was able to confirm that LD_LIBRARY_PATH is the same when the browser is running the code or when I run things manually in IPython.